# networkaddress.cache.ttl null in openjdk

Tags: java, java-8

When I perform:

```
System.getProperty("networkaddress.cache.ttl");
Security.getProperty("networkaddress.cache.ttl");
```

result is null.

I am using alpine, openJdk8.
I did some tests and saw that my resources dns are changing, it is my desired behaviour, resolve dns, not cache forever.

I read that if SecurityManager is installed, default value is: -1, that means "cache dns forever"

I do not have SecurityManager installed.

What is the correct behaviour for this case?
When SecurityManager is not installed and networkaddress.cache.ttl is null?
Dns cache will be flush or not?

Comment: Same with OpenJDK 11 without SecurityManager.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The settings are actually in the configuration files.

## OpenJDK 8

Using the Docker image [openjdk:8](https://hub.docker.com/layers/openjdk/library/openjdk/8/images/sha256-e820585a112dd031fe7cfad27c4bf846dacbdd15616aa9e61255afd99e4a1da9), the implementation uses 30 seconds when there is no security manager.

`/usr/local/openjdk-8/jre/lib/security/java.security` :

```
#
# The Java-level namelookup cache policy for successful lookups:
#
# any negative value: caching forever
# any positive value: the number of seconds to cache an address for
# zero: do not cache
#
# default value is forever (FOREVER). For security reasons, this
# caching is made forever when a security manager is set. When a security
# manager is not set, the default behavior in this implementation
# is to cache for 30 seconds.
#
# NOTE: setting this to anything other than the default value can have
#       serious security implications. Do not set it unless
#       you are sure you are not exposed to DNS spoofing attack.
#
#networkaddress.cache.ttl=-1
```

## OpenJDK 11

Using the Docker image openjdk:11, the implementation is the same as above.

`/usr/local/openjdk-11/conf/security/java.security` :

```
#
# The Java-level namelookup cache policy for successful lookups:
#
# any negative value: caching forever
# any positive value: the number of seconds to cache an address for
# zero: do not cache
#
# default value is forever (FOREVER). For security reasons, this
# caching is made forever when a security manager is set. When a security
# manager is not set, the default behavior in this implementation
# is to cache for 30 seconds.
#
# NOTE: setting this to anything other than the default value can have
#       serious security implications. Do not set it unless
#       you are sure you are not exposed to DNS spoofing attack.
#
#networkaddress.cache.ttl=-1
```

In some other versions, it can be under /etc, e.g. `/etc/java-11-openjdk/security/java.security`

Using AdoptOpenJDK 11, you can see the [TTL is set to 30 seconds when no security manager is found](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk/blob/jdk-11+28/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/net/InetAddressCachePolicy.java#L120).

Comment: How do you know if a "security manager" is set or not set? is there a way to inspect the value of this property on a running jvm?

Comment: @xref `System.getSecurityManager()` returns `null` if there is none: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/security.html

I have tried reading the property at runtime, it was unset (like in the question). That's how I came to read more about it and find this :)

Comment: I was mainly curious if I could use `jcmd` or another tool to either read the value of `networkaddress.cache.ttl` for a running jvm, since I don't have access to modify the code

Comment: In case of Java 11, you could use `jshell` to check if security manager exists.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question "how to get these values"

Comment: My question was not the source question but your post saved my day!  Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome @ludacris2k4 :-)