# How to get and set the value of networkaddress.cache.ttl

Tags: java, security, parameters, dns

I have a java application running in an alpine container. I would like to find a reliable way to determine what is the value of `networkaddress.cache.ttl`. I tried to use this in the code of the application: `java.security.Security.getProperty("networkaddress.cache.ttl");` but it always returns null, even when I use `-Dnetworkaddress.cache.ttl=30` in the JAVA_OPTS arguments. So I am doing something wrong obviously but I don't know what. According to this
[networkaddress.cache.ttl null in openjdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58732528/networkaddress-cache-ttl-null-in-openjdk) I don't even need to add the argument in JAVA_OPTS because the default value is 30 anyway. Looking at `/usr/local/openjdk-8/jre/lib/security/java.security` inside the container I can see `#networkaddress.cache.ttl=-1` but it is commented out, so I have no idea what the default value is. So how can i reliably check what is the value of `networkaddress.cache.ttl`?

Comment: this might help you https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/java-dg-jvm-ttl.html

Comment: Thank you @Toerktumlare I was looking for getting the value first and then if I didn't like the value then I'd set it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reasons unknown to me `-Dnetworkaddress.cache.ttl=30` fails to set anything. I managed to set it by adding this to my Dockerfile

```
sed -i '313,313 s/^#//' /usr/lib/jvm/zulu8-ca/jre/lib/security/java.security
sed -i '313,313 s/-1/30/' /usr/lib/jvm/zulu8-ca/jre/lib/security/java.security
```

Another way it can be done is described [here](https://dzone.com/articles/how-override-java-security). The idea is to use another file for overriding the security property.
Both approaches worked fine for me.

Comment: It's unclear what line 313 contains and what code changes this the above snippet actually entails.

Comment: @Alex It's been a long time since then and my hard drive is really small. All files are temporary, so i don't remember. But I think line 313 is from a standard config file mentioned in there.

Answer (score 2):

```
According to the [JDK 11 docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html):
```

> Since these 2 properties are part of the security policy, they are not set by either the -D option or the System.setProperty() API, instead they are set as security properties.

A [note from AWS Java SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/java-dg-jvm-ttl.html) uses SecurityProperty instead of SystemProperty as in:

```java
java.security.Security.setProperty("networkaddress.cache.ttl" , "60");
```

so you could use

```java
String ttl = java.security.Security.getProperty("networkaddress.cache.ttl");
```

Comment: Great point supported with a great reference! The point being that network cache ttl settings won't work with -D cli options.